# Google Calendar subscription shared with iCloud

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical, google-calendar

Is it possible to share a Google Calendar subscription with multiple iCloud users? My sister has given me complete shared access to her Google Calendar so I can publish it to my iCloud calendar and share that with all the iOS users in the family.

Initially I simply exported the calendar file and imported it in OS X's Calendar App, then shared the new iCloud calendar. I have been notified that this calendar will now be updated on a regular basis.

I have been unable to locate any type of sync settings or app that would keep these two calendars in sync. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're trying to tank an airplane with cardiesel here. You cannot just mix them together.

Answer (score 1):

You can not sync a Google calendar and an iCloud calendar out of the box. (Google and Apple both seem to avoid making it possible, probably because they both try to pull users onto their side.)

However:

1. All Apple devices can use and sync with Google calendars additional to iCloud calendars (I use it a lot with >10 Google calendars from >5 different users)
2. I saw some syncing tools that keep iCloud and Google calendars in sync, but a) they have to be always running somewhere and b) they are usually hacky and unstable.

You can Google both; I recommend 1.